# Java convert DateTime from "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" or from "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Tags: java, java-11, java-time

Java 11

I want to convert the date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS" to either "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" or "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" based on milliseconds value. If milliseconds are all zeros, then I just want single zero but if it is non-zero value then I want just value omitting trailing zeros.

Example :

1. Input : 2021-03-10 16:37:02.4230000 =>
   Desired Output : 2021-03-10 16:37:02.423
2. Input : 2021-03-10 16:39:51.0000000 => Desired output : 2021-03-10 16:39:51.0
3. Input : 2021-04-22 23:03:52.0234000 => Desired output : 2021-04-22 23:03:52.0234

Comment: You don't "change" the format, container classes, like `LocalDateTime` do not have a concept of formatting, this is what a `DateTimeFormatter` is for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I started out with something like...

```
String text = "2021-03-10 16:37:02.4230000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");

LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-03-10 16:37:02.4230000", formatter);
DateTimeFormatter shortFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
System.out.println(shortFormatter.format(ldt1));

LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-03-10 16:39:51.0000000", formatter);
System.out.println(shortFormatter.format(ldt2));
```

Which prints out ...

```
2021-03-10 16:37:02.4
2021-03-10 16:39:51.0
```

Hmmm , not quite what we're looking for.

Lucky for us, there's the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class.  So next, I tried something like...

```
DateTimeFormatter toFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
        .toFormatter();

System.out.println(toFormatter.format(ldt1));
System.out.println(toFormatter.format(ldt2));
```

Which prints out ...

```
2021-03-10 16:37:02.423
2021-03-10 16:39:51.0
```

Success

Now, please note, I've not really used `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` before, so there might be some other, really super awesome cool way to achieve the same or better result, but hay, it's a nice start

Comment: I consider it a very fine solution. It will of course print 2 or 4 or 9 decimals if so many are non-zero. Whether this will be acceptable, only the OP can tell.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. This solves my problem, just how can I make it work for this case ? From "2021-04-22 23:03:52.0234000" to "2021-04-22 23:03:52.0234"? Current logic returns "2021-04-22 23:03:52.023".

Comment: It worked by changing MillsOfSecond to NanoOFSecond.                                                                  DateTimeFormatter toFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 7, true)
                    .toFormatter();

Comment: Full Code : public static String transformDateFormatsWithMills(String date) {
            DateTimeFormatter toFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 7, true)
                    .toFormatter();
            return LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS")).format(toFormatter);
        }
    p s v main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(transformDateFormatsWithMills("2021-04-22 23:03:52.0234000"));
    }

Answer (score 0):

This can done using `replaceAll` method of String as well. you can remove the trailing zero's in the date string if there is no milisecond left after removing all trailing zero's, then append `.0`

```
private static String getMiliSecond(String input) {
        // removing trailing zeros
        String miliSecondTrimmed = input.replaceAll("[0.]*$", "");
        // if there is there is no mili second left after removing zeros, append .0 
        return (!miliSecondTrimmed.contains("."))?(miliSecondTrimmed+(".0").toString()):miliSecondTrimmed;
    }
```

This code called from main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input1 ="2021-03-10 16:39:51.0000000";
        String input2 = "2021-03-10 16:37:02.4230000";
        String miliSecond1 = getMiliSecond(input1);
        String miliSecond2 = getMiliSecond(input2);
        System.out.println("input1 mili:"+miliSecond1);
        System.out.println("input2 mili:"+miliSecond2);

    }
```

**Output:**

```
input1 mili:2021-03-10 16:39:51.0
input2 mili:2021-03-10 16:37:02.423
```